# Two fields from the same table

Tags: sql, join

I have a table with auditors name and another one with the senior auditors that will evaluate auditors.

auditors ( id, name )
1, ademir
2, luana
3, ana

evaluations ( id, idevaluator, idevaluated )
1, 1, 2
2, 1, 3

Ademir will evaluate luana and ana.

So I have to list:
Ademir "will evaluate" luana
Ademir "will evaluate" ana

and I could not create a select that show me that.

If someone knows how to do it, I would appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just `JOIN` the `auditors` table twice:

```
SELECT * 
FROM auditors a1
INNER JOIN evaluations e
  ON a1.id = e.idevaluator
INNER JOIN auditors a2
  ON e.idevaluated = a2.id
```

Comment: So simple. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You have to join the table `Auditors` twice with the use of aliasses

```
select t1.name, t2.name 
from Auditors t1 
join Evaluations on t1.id = idevaluator 
join Auditors t2 on t2.id = idevaluated
```